# how to detect in case statement if the value of the field is a string "0" in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

in oracle, How to detect in case statement if the value of the field is in "0", then set it to ""?
because I have a problem detecting it when i use something like this

```
case 
  when REGEXP_LIKE (ctyid, '^[:DIGIT]') then '""'
```

it doesn't work, am still getting "0" in the output..i want to set it to ""

Comment: Can you give some example? a simple `ctyid = '0'` does not work?

Comment: yes, it doesn't..still getting "0"

Comment: problem solved, my error was, i first did the when ctyid is not null, i should have checked if it's equal to '0' before checking if it's not null to get the '""' value..thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to look for 0 anywhere in the string, then use `LIKE` operator :

`WHEN ctyid LIKE '%0%' THEN NULL`

That would return NULL value if 0 is found anywhere in the string.

If you want to look for the value as 0 itself, then use `=` operator.

`WHEN ctyid = '0' THEN NULL`

`CASE` looks easier to read, but the same expression could be written as `DECODE` :

`DECODE(cytid, '0', NULL, cytid)`

Answer (score 1):

Please reference the documentation of [Regular Expression Syntax in ORACLE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm)

Right expression should be:

```
case 
  when REGEXP_LIKE (ctyid, '^[[:digit:]]') then '""' else ctyid end
```

OR

```
case 
  when REGEXP_LIKE (ctyid, '^\d') then '""' else ctyid end
```

But your sample code would match all `ctyid` start with a number, not only with `0` in it.

**UPDATE**

According to @LalitKumarB's comment, I have to append following code that I think it should be finished by the OPself.

```
case 
  when REGEXP_LIKE (ctyid, '^0') then '""' else ctyid end
```

Comment: How does this answer OP's question? Your query would find any digit and not just `0`.

Comment: @LalitKumarB  I skipped all verbal fluff and relied on the code.

Comment: The answer section is **ONLY** meant for answers. Rest other suggestions etc. should be only in **comments**.